# I got empty result with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have tried to show the whole table data in MySQL. Rows are (User_id, first_name, last_name, and dept). There is no result when I refresh the page.

```
<?php
$servername = "fdb19.awardspace.net";
$username = "2598428_db";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "2598428_db";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql="SELECT * From users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo $res['AverageSatisfactionScore'];
} 

?>
```

Comment: [Read this](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/using-object-oriented-php-with-the-mysqli-extension/).

Answer (score 2):

Your echo is false.

You need to display a valid column name like :
`echo $res['id']` or `echo $res['dept']`.

Answer (score 0):

just try to print the total count of your result set by

`echo mysqli_num_rows( $result );`

it will print total number of records in the result

Also try to print whole row by

`print_r($res);`

insted of using

`echo $res['AverageSatisfactionScore'];`